# How can I replace one of two JPanels with another JPanel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I designed an interface for the welcome screen with one JFrame included two JPanels (JPanel1 on right and JPanel2 on left). The buttons on the left is to switch the Panels in JPanel1. I want to press on a button to replace JPanel1 content with another JPanel but I don`t know how. Please help.

Comment: Post the code you have so far. One easy solution would be to use the `CardLayout` on your JPanel1 and when you press your button, you can call `CardLayout.next()`.

Comment: I don`t want to use CardLayout because the current design is better for the client. About the code, I used Netbeans for drag and drop. The interface is divided into two JPanels the buttons on the left and I want the effect of the button to change the JPanel on the right with another one.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but would declaring a variable JPanel JPanelOnLeft and changing its value work? E.g. you could initialize JPanelOnLeft to JPanelOnLeftInitializationValue and then, when the user clicks a button to replace the content of that panel, set JPanelOnLeft to JPanelOnLeftContainingUserRequestedContent.

Comment: _I don`t want to use CardLayout because the current design is better for the client._ Visually it won't change a thing for the user and in term of technical design, this is likely one of the best option you could get.

Comment: I need a code to do this algorithm: When clicking on button1OnLeft then replace the JPanel1 with JPanel88.When clicking on button2OnLeft then replace the JPanel1 with JPanel89. and so on.  @GuillaumePolet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best answer I found is that I will create one JFrame only and gonna make one big JPanel include two JPanels (JPanelLeft include the buttons and JPanelRight include what the button do) then I will copy the main JPanel for each JButton. 
When I press on any button I will do (JFrame.getContentPane.removeAll) to remove the old JPanel then (JFrame.getContentPane.Add(NewJPanel).

This works for me and keep my design as I Want. Thanks for every body.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very simple example of something that should approximate your description. On the left, we have a hug button to toggle the content of the right panel. On the right, you have a panel with a given border and a label. When you press the button, the content on the right is swapped with the other panel.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestCardLayout2 {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Left panel");
        leftPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JButton button = new JButton("Toggle right panel");
        leftPanel.add(button);
        frame.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        rightPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 500));

        JPanel rightPanel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        rightPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        JPanel rightPanel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        rightPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Right panel 1 with a red border");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Right panel 2 with a blue borer");
        rightPanel1.add(label1);
        rightPanel2.add(label2);

        rightPanel.add(rightPanel1, "panel1");
        rightPanel.add(rightPanel2, "panel2");
        frame.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.next(rightPanel);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestCardLayout2().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string ...

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy My bad, in version prior to JVM7, you have to provide a "String" constraint when you add components to the container using the CardLayout. You can pass any String as a second argument of the `add` method, as long as you make sure that they are all different for all components contained.

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy I added the two `String` "constraints" so that it works in all Java version

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `CardLayout` would be `JRootPane` and its `JRootPane.setContentPane()` method. Here's an example:

```
final JPanel panel1 = ...;
final JPanel panel2 = ...;
boolean showingPanel1 = true;
final JRootPane rootPane = new JRootPane();
rootPane.setContentPane(panel1);
JButton switchButton = new JButton("Switch");
switchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (showingPanel1) {
            rootPane.setContentPane(panel2);
        } else {
            rootPane.setContentPane(panel1);
        }
        showingPanel = !showingPanel;
    }
});
```

Add the `rootPane` and `switchButton` components to your window, and then clicking `switchButton` will switch out the panels.

Here's a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html). You should mostly be concerned with `JRootPane.setContentPane`, the other stuff in the tutorial isn't relevant.

Comment: Thanks, but how this code will replace only the right JPanle with the new one. I don`t want to change what all the Jframe include as one Panel.

Comment: Literally replace your right-hand `JPanel` with the `JRootPane`. Where you call `add(rightPanel)`, call `add(rootPane)` instead, then just call `setContentPane(rightPanel)` on the `JRootPane`, not the `JFrame`. When you want to switch, call `setContentPane` with the new panel.

Comment: Why are you creating a JRootPane? JFrame (and JWindow and JDialog and JInetrnalFrame) already has a JRootPane installed?  This is just adding fluff and confusion...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Because it's a nested root pane. If the OP was replacing the entire window, then yes, you'd just use the frame itself. Since he's trying to replace the contents of a specific panel that's alongside other components inside the window, you can't just use the window's root pane, you have to create your own.

Comment: So why not just use `remove`/`add` directly?