# Replacing current JPanel from JButton inside the JPanel not the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have a JFrame and I use it as the main one and change JPanels inside the same JFrame. The first JPanel is already inside the JFrame ,so I can replace it by "this.removeall() then ,this.setContentPane(new JPanel2)" because "this" here invoke the JFrame itself.

In the other JPanel, I want to make a JButton to replace the current JPanel with another one. The problem is that I can`t do the same code before because "this" here invoke the JPanel not the JFrame.

The question is how can I write the code inside the JPanel allow me to get the JFrame to change its "setContentPane" to view the second Panel?

---

I have found the answer in using CardLayout .. this video helped me solve the problem

[CardLayout on Netbeans video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-zSU6vNwYw)

Comment: Why not use a `CardLayout` for that group of panels?

Comment: @AndrewThompson-In the design of the interface we used buttons not CardLayout or Tabs. I wanted to make all the application Panels and change them one by one in one JFrame

Comment: I want to write the code of changing the JPanels inside the button in the JPanel itself not the JFrame - @AndrewThompson

Comment: What do you mean by *"inside the button in the JPanel"*  - The code should not extend button or panel.

Comment: I mean, this will be the function of the button.

Comment: I want to write the code in the buttonActionListner in the JPanel. I will not write that code in the JFrame, so every JPanel can be added and removed to call another one independently

Comment: All the answers on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372302/how-can-i-replace-one-of-two-jpanels-with-another-jpanel-in-java) covering this exact topic were completely valid, you know. `CardLayout` and `JRootPane` are both very reasonable (and very common) solutions to this exact problem.

Comment: @Brian Thank you The problem solved using CardLAyout

Answer (score 2):

> I want to write the code in the buttonActionListner in the JPanel. I will not write that code in the JFrame, so every JPanel can be added and removed to call another one independently

and

> @AndrewThompson-In the design of the interface we used buttons not CardLayout or Tabs. I wanted to make all the application Panels and change them one by one in one JFrame

have to call for parent (`JFrame`, `JPanel`),

```
validate(); // for Java7 revalidate() for JFrame
repaint();
```

after remove an add a new `JPanel`, only once time and as last code line

as `@AndrewThompson` mentioned better, easiest and simpliest way could be to use CardLayout

Comment: OK, but how can I call the JFrame of the current JPanel

Comment: create instance of JFrame don't extends for JFrame, never, but in this case its looks like as you to have to put father panel that holds child panel that you want to remove, this is a tax for using GUI builder